# Devise 'trackable' without firing model callbacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

One of [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) modules is [trackable](http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Trackable)

Which is used to Track information about your user sign in.

My `user.rb` model obeys devise for following modules.

```
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable,
       :rememberable, :token_authenticatable
```

I want to add `:trackable` to it [but when it updates the respective fields](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/trackable.rb#L18-L32) it should not fire any callbacks from `User` model.

One solution would be to conditionally check every callback for the tracable fields changes.

Is there an elegant way to do this ? Probably without the callback check.

Comment: override it? unsure of the actual implementation - but that was what i did when devise wasn't doing exactly what i wanted. or if you really wanted you could change the actual code.